# Using SecureZeroMemory with std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, buffer-overflow, securezeromemory

Here is my code:

```
std::vector<WCHAR> sString(6);
DWORD dwSize= sString.size(); // dwSize is 6
SIZE_T dwSizeof=sizeof(sString); // dwSizeof is 16
StringCchCopy(sString.data(), dwSize, L"asdfa");  // a, s, d, f, a, \0
SecureZeroMemory(sString, dwSize);  // \0, \0, \0, f, a, \0
SecureZeroMemory(sString, dwSizeof);  // \0, \0, \0, \0, \0, \0
```

Which value do I put into the size parameter of SecureZeroMemory? If I put in dwSize, only the first three characters change to '\0'. If I put dwSizeof, all get cleared, but that looks like a buffer overflow?

Comment: Simply `sString.size() * sizeof(WCHAR)`, as for any `vector` and element type: number of elements times size of each element. `sizeof(sString)` is very much **not** what you want, as that's just the `vector`'s internal implementation details like pointer to buffer, etc.

Comment: And first parameter should be sString.data().